# Qt как осуществить перехват пакетов по сети?

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

Изучаю Qt, прочитал разделы книги Шлее М. по работе сетью в частности работы tcp и udp протоколов, созданию простых приложений по передаче и приёму информации по данным протоколам.
Но не могу понять, как осуществить приём любых пакетов, с любых портов при работе с конкретной сетью.
Подскажите в каком направлении идти дальше.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону драйверов.

Comment: Из вопроса не очень понятно, вам надо именно перехват, или просто уметь получать из самописной программы пакеты с не известного заранее адреса и порта?

Comment: Я не понимаю, как и возможно ли средствами qt выявить передачу данных по сети, уточнить на каком порту и получить эти данные.

Comment: скорее всего нужен pcap.

Answer (score 0):

Вспоминаем матчасть. Для получения "всех" пакетов вам нужно опуститься до транспортного уровня минуя протокольные слои, в понятиях модели OSI. Qt таких возможностей не предоставляет и врядли будет предоставлять в будущем, так как это не его задача.

Если Qt отбросить, то вам нужно смотреть в сторону т. н. [сырых сокетов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82) (raw socket). Они плохо стандартизированы, точнее еще хуже чем обычные сокеты, каждый лепит как хочет. Однако подразумевается что пакеты вы получаете без обработки. Ну и соотвественно всю обработку, разбор по протоколам, придется самому делать.

Если нужен совсем хардкор, то посмотрите [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org).